# How do I manage assembly versions in a multiple module / customer scenario?

Tags: module, assemblies, versioning

I need some guidance on managing assemblies and versions and the source control thereof.

First, a little background on the application. The app is an ERP-type system where several customers can run various modules; some of them 
standard and/or some of them customised specifically for the customer. Each module implements a particular business function or variation thereof.
The rationale is that these modules can be interchanged / customised easily without affecting other modules or requiring a rebuild.

The application is based on an application shell, an application core and then the run-time loaded modules.  All the customers use the 
application shell and core and then any number of modules. Currently I have about 70+ modules.

The application core consists of 2 assemblies. The first being the services/business logic, data access layers, data objects, etc. 
The second is all the base UI forms, dialogs, etc.

The modules are each implemented as an assembly of their own (as a VS project in the solution). Each of these projects reference the 2 core 
assemblies. These module assemblies are loaded at runtime when the application starts up. So, to change a module, one can simply 
replace the assembly. The main application shell creates the application core class instances.

Now the scenario is this:
- When I change a module, its assembly version gets bumped.

- When I change the implementation of a core assembly method (i.e. do not change any class signatures), then I dont need a 
  rebuild of the dependent modules and therefore their versions remain as is. However, the core assembly version gets bumped.
- When I add a property or method to a core class, then I also dont need a rebuild of the dependent modules and therefore their versions 
  remain as is. Again, core assembly version gets bumped.
- However, when I change the signature of a core class, I need a rebuild of all the dependent assemblies. Should I bump each module 
  version in this case?

**Version control**

Seeing that each module is a separate project, they each have a different root element in the VSS tree. So should I label each module 
node with the version?

What is the best way to manage the version dependencies? Excel?

Also, each customer's deployment is now a release (with a number), but with a set of modules, each having their respective assembly versions.
How the hell do I keep track of this?

I would appreciate any suggestions / comments about the versioning but also the philosophy of having to manage this catalog of modules

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - Stop using VSS and use a real version control system like Subversion, Mercurial, or Git that allows you to effectively use branches and tags. This will help a *ton* when it comes to managing different setups and dependencies.

**Step 2** - Follow the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) guidelines, and do it for each module or versioned item. This will give your other elements that depend on a particular module an easy way to determine the *scope* the next version of one of their dependent modules

In general, a module's version should only change according to the semantic versioning guidelines, which are entirely focused on how the module's ***external API*** changes. So, if a dependent module's version changes, but there are no changes to the external API of the module we are dealing with, you would bump the patch version number (eg. `1.12.5 -> 1.12.6`)

If you use tags and branches in your version control system, one for each deployed version, you will be able to easily keep track of what depends on what because it's recorded in the version control history. Having different customers on different branches gives you all the flexibility you need, and you don't have to track anything extra, so no extra overhead.